# How to split array to sub-arrays of elements with same values ? (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the array `[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]`

Is there any elegant way I can split it to sub-arrays, so that each array contains elements with same values?

I want to achieve the following result:

```
result = [[1], [2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4], [5], [6]]
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It seems pretty much the same problem to me, feel free to ask for reopening if not.

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

Code

```
p a.slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.to_a
```

output

```
[[1], [2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4], [5], [6]]
```